# Creating new field with floating values from already existing string field using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, floating

Iт QGIS 3.10 I have imported a CSV which contains a column of numeric data (let's call this attribute `"x"`). However, it is imported automatically as strings. I can easily create a new field by clicking the Field Calculator and typing `to_real("x")`.

Because I need to repeat this many times, I would like to use PyQGIS to do this.

I've been trying various ways but I still can't get it to work. For example, I was following this: [Struggling to use Field Calculator - PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303350/struggling-to-use-field-calculator-pyqgis)

Could someone please tell me what I did wrong?

```py
#import data
csv_file = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_csv, 'nameoflayer')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(csv_file)

csv = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('nameoflayer')[0]

#start editing this layer
with edit(csv):
    for feature in selected_feature:
        feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('newfieldname'), to_real(feature['x']))
        updateFeature(feature)
```

There is no error message but I can't see the new column called `"newfieldname"` when I open the attribute table after running the above code.

Comment: Does your table already have `newfieldname` or do you want to add it using PyQGIS? Do you define `selected_feature` before using in `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to_real` is a function belonging to Field Calculator. Its Python equivalent is `float`. I assume `"newfieldname"` already exists in the attribute table. Use this script:

```py
csv = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('nameoflayer')[0]

with edit(csv):
    csv.addAttribute(QgsField('newfieldname', QVariant.Double))

    for feature in csv.getFeatures(): # OR csv.selectedFeatures():
        feature['newfieldname'] = float(feature['x'])
        csv.updateFeature(feature)
```

Comment: Thank you! No actually newfieldname does not exist yet! And I did try creating one by using the code below, but it's also not working :( It doesn't show up. 
`csv.startEditing()
csv.addAttributes([QgsField('newfieldname',  QVariant.Int)]) 
csv.commitChanges()`

Comment: You should use `addAttribute` instead of `addAttributes` under `edit`.  Also, when using `addAttribute` you don't need to use the brackets `[...]`. And since you use `edit`, you don't need to use `commitChanges()`.  I've edited the answer.